# Scifi Short Story Collection with a Troll-type Creature Sitting on Flower

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a scifi short story collection. I was about 12 when I read it (34 now) and at the time I felt that the book was much older than me (possibly a 70s-80s pocket book).
The cover had a squat, troll-looking creature in space sitting or standing on a flower. The cover was based on a story in which the creature was being held in some kind of observational cell. It is described as being responsible for creating either the universe or the human race. In the end of the story, I believe some soldiers shoot and kill it.

I don't remember any other stories from the collection.